# @autowired and null ref exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

//Located in com\src\myproject\services

```
package com.src.myproject.services;

public interface IMyService {
    public boolean Method1();

}
```

//Located in com\src\myproject\services

```
package com.src.myproject.services;

public class MyService implements IMyService {


    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @Override
    public boolean Method1() {


        return gettestMapper().GetOrder(1); //Get null pointer exception as testMapper is null in debug mode
    }



    public TestMapper gettestMapper(){

            return testMapper;
        }


    public void settestMapper(TestMapper testMapper){
        this.testMapper=testMapper;
        }

}
```

My `mapper.java` files are located under `com\src\mappers`

and corresponding `mapper.xml` is located under `src\main\resources\com\src\myproject\mappers`

My `servelet-context.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties,/WEB-INF/spring/mybatis.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.src.myproject.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.src.myproject.services" />


    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}" p:user="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="10" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    autowire="byName" />


    <!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="${typeAliasesPackage}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.src.myproject.mappers" />
         <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

The autowiring in the services files is always null and gives null ref exception when I try to use any method from the mapper files via auto wire.

Comment: How do you obtain an instance of `MyService`? You aren't calling `new MyService()`, aren't you?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: In the controller, it is instantiated as `IMyService mySvc = new Service();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never instantiate Spring beans directly. It's the container that is responsible for object creation. Thus in your controller, instead of:

```
IMyService mySvc = new Service();
```

Create such field:

```
@Autowired
private IMyService mySvc;
```

Spring will discover it and assign proper value, which is an instance of `MyService` creates beforehand for you.

Comment: That gives this Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.src.myproejct.services.IMyService com.src.myproject.controllers.MyController.myService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.src.myproject.services.IMyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

help?

Comment: GIves `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Error occured processing XML 'At least one base 
  package must be specified'. See Error Log for more details
 - cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must 
  appear on element 'context:component-scan'.`

Comment: In your service you have not annotated the class with @Service, or its one of its alternatives

Comment: Yes I did place that annotation. Let me perform a clean build.

Comment: @craftand: You suggestion also helped. cannot mark 2 comments as answers. but many thanks